# Swift: Check String if it has an element in an Array

Tags: arrays, string, swift

I want to check if a string contains at least one element in an array.

I tried this but I think it's too long. Imagine if I want all the alphabet in the if statement. I hope there is a proper way to do this.

```
var str = "Hello, playground."

let typeString = NSString(string: str)

if typeString.containsString("a") || typeString.containsString("e") || typeString.containsString("i") || typeString.containsString("o") || typeString.containsString("u") {
print("yes")
} else { 
print("no")
}
// yes
```

I tried using an array but it doesn't work. It needs all of the elements in an array to have a result of "yes".

```
let vowels = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]
if typeString.containsString("\(vowels)") {
print("yes")
} else {
print("no")
}
// no
```

Btw, I'm still a newbie and still learning. Hope someone can help. Thanks

Comment: Do you understand why your second attempt failed? That will help you solve this problem.

Comment: @aaron Yes, I think it is because I did put the whole array in containsString but I'm not sure how to check at least one of the array contains the string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create two sets with the string characters and check its intersection:

```
let str = "Hello, playground."
let set = Set("aeiou")
let intersection = Set(str).intersection(set)
if !intersection.isEmpty {
    print("Vogals found:", intersection)                        // {"u", "o", "e", "a"}
    print("Vogals not found:", set.subtracting(intersection))   // {"i"}
} else {
    print("No vogal found")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this switch statements.

```
let mySentence = "Hello Motto"
var findMyVowel: Character = "a" 
switch findMyVowel { 
case "a","e","i","o","u": 
    print("yes") 
default:
    print("no")
} 
mySentence.containsString("e")
```

Comment: `let sentence =  "Hello Motto"`
`let containsVowel = sentence.contains {`
    `switch $0 {`
    `case "a","e","i","o","u":`
        `return true`
    `default:`
        `return false`
    `}`
`}`
`print(containsVowel)`